# Transform position is not updating during animation in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have exported **3D Max Animation** (Car Animation) FBX in unity, it is working fine.

Now, I want to move my object(cube) according to car animation so, I created a cube, make the child of the car object. **But** the problem is,  cube is not moving along with the car (animated object). I checked in the inspector that my car object transform position is not changing.

Comment: Not an expert on animations but, when you animate an object, you should just animate in a fixed position, let's say a walking animation. The character needs to move on a spot. Not actually move in the animation. Because you will use the animation and transform its position in Unity. As your car, create a moving animation but make sure it stays in a fixed position. Then change its position in Unity. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-Zw2k7p9vc) for moving a character

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Apply Root Motion" in your car's animator component.

Comment: I am using Animation type legacy